# Elastic - updating multiple documents in a single request

Tags: c#, json, elasticsearch, nest

I need to update several thousand items every several minutes in Elastic and unfortunately **reindexing is not an option for me**. From my research the best way to update an item is using [_update_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) - I have had success updating single documents like so -

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "itemId": {
        "query": "1"
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.field = params.updateValue",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "updateValue": "test",
    }
  }
}
```

```c#
var response = await Client.UpdateByQueryAsync<dynamic>(q => q
    .Index("masterproducts")
    .Query(q => x.MatchQuery)
    .Script(s => s.Source(x.Script).Lang("painless").Params(x.Params))
    .Conflicts(Elasticsearch.Net.Conflicts.Proceed)
);
```

Although this works it is extremely inefficient as it generates thousands of requests - is there a way in which I can update multiple documents with a matching ID in a single request? I have already tried [Multiple search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) which it would seem cannot be used for this purpose. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, try to generalize your query.

Instead of targeting a single `itemId`, perhaps try using a [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "itemId": [
        "1", "2", ...
      ]
    }
  },
  "script": {
    ...
  }
}
```

From the looks of it, your (seemingly simplified) script sets the **same** value, irregardless of the document ID / `itemId`. So that's that.

If the script does indeed set **different** values based on the doc IDs / `itemIds`, you could make the `params` multi-value:

```
"params": {
 "updateValue1": "test1",
 "updateValue2": "test2",
 ...
}
```

and then [dynamically access](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-update-by-query-context.html) them:

```
...
def value_to_set = params['updateValue' + ctx._source['itemId']];
...
```

so the target doc is updated with the corresponding value.